# Transform JavaScript 2D Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, django, google-visualization

I am creating a dashboard to show data from various stats. I am using Django and [Google Charts](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/quick_start) for creating graphs. It has been good so far but  I am stuck at one particular case.

the model class is-

```
class Registration(models.Model):
    event_type = models.CharField(max_length=80)
    date_time = models.DateField()
    count = models.IntegerField()
```

my query is-

```
Registration.objects.filter(event_type__in=['VHRAssmntCompleted', 
    'VNAAssmntCompleted', 
    'NonsmokersDeclrtn',
    'MWBAssmntCompleted',
    'VHCAssmntCompleted',
    'SV Document Uploads',
    'PapSmear',
    'Mammogram',], 
    date_time__range=(d3,d1)).order_by('date_time')
```

I get the data in following format:

```
[["VHR", "2019-02-1", 23],
["VNA", "2019-02-1", 34],
["PAP", "2019-02-1", 50],
["VHR", "2019-02-2", 92],
["VNA", "2019-02-2", 13],
["PAP", "2019-02-2", 65],
["VHR", "2019-02-3", 192],
["VNA", "2019-02-3", 43],
["PAP", "2019-02-3", 11]]
```

To create a [Combo Chart](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/combochart) in need the data in following format(something like python dataframe):

```
[["date", "VHR", "VNA", "PAP" ],
["2019-02-1", 23,34,50],
["2019-02-2", 92,13,65],
["2019-02-3", 192,43,11]]
```

I am unable to find a way to do this, either format it using Django ORM query itself or transform using JS.

I need help with what approach should I go.

Comment: check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53439490/5090771) for using google charts `group()` method, without having to hard-code the column headings as in the answers here...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could take an object for the column position of the values and collect the data by date and column.

```js
var data = [["VHR", "2019-02-1", 23], ["VNA", "2019-02-1", 34], ["PAP", "2019-02-1", 50], ["VHR", "2019-02-2", 92], ["VNA", "2019-02-2", 13], ["PAP", "2019-02-2", 65], ["VHR", "2019-02-3", 192], ["VNA", "2019-02-3", 43], ["PAP", "2019-02-3", 11]],
    cols = { VHR: 1, VNA: 2, PAP: 3 },
    result = data.reduce((r, [key, date, value]) => {
        var row = r.find(([d]) => d === date);
        if (!row) {
            r.push(row = [date, 0, 0, 0]);
        }
        row[cols[key]] = value;
        return r;    
    }, [["date", "VHR", "VNA", "PAP"]]);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 2):

you can group them by date, then using `Object.entries` loop through the grouped result and transform it to `[date, "VHR", "VNA", "PAP"]`

```js
const data = [
  ["VHR", "2019-02-1", 23],
  ["VNA", "2019-02-1", 34],
  ["PAP", "2019-02-1", 50],
  ["VHR", "2019-02-2", 92],
  ["VNA", "2019-02-2", 13],
  ["PAP", "2019-02-2", 65],
  ["VHR", "2019-02-3", 192],
  ["VNA", "2019-02-3", 43],
  ["PAP", "2019-02-3", 11]
];

const grouped = data.reduce((all, [key, date, value]) => {

  all[date] = {
    ...all[date],
    [key]: value
  };

  return all;
}, {});

const result = ["date", "VHR", "VNA", "PAP"].concat(
  Object.entries(grouped).map(([date, obj]) => [date, ...Object.values(obj)])
);

console.log(result);
```