# How do I change data structure for use with google line chart

Tags: php, arrays, json, data-structures, google-visualization

I have a json api feed that I want to restructure for use in a google line chart but I don't know how to loop over the json data to create a new array in php. To complicate things the data I want to plot for each item is on different rows.

This is the json data

```
{
    "records": [
        {
            "id": "2",
            "groupno": "1",
            "urlsource": "https://www.amazon.co.uk/Boot-Buddy-fastest-simplest-footwear/dp/B014UPAHO4?pd_rd_wg=lVVK6&pd_rd_r=bf1ba871-fb59-4c66-a146-e94dde7c8e6d&pd_rd_w=gWC2F&ref_=pd_gw_ri&pf_rd_r=W68MX1TXFDDJ8Q8Z08CP&pf_rd_p=cecd4520-32f6-5499-ae19-cd4e83816acd",
            "name": "Boot buddy",
            "date": "2019-04-14 16:00:29.595",
            "price": "£14.99"
        },
        {
            "id": "1",
            "groupno": "1",
            "urlsource": "https://www.amazon.co.uk/dp/B07CH6JKW3/ref=gw_uk_desk_h1_aucc_cp_mp?pf_rd_p=e4e5a2e6-ddbd-473a-a5fb-e8cc09a11f88&pf_rd_r=1MN25BRXY8YDQ4TBK4X6",
            "name": "Amazon echo",
            "date": "2019-04-14 16:00:29.595",
            "price": "£19.99"
        },
        {
            "id": "2",
            "groupno": "1",
            "urlsource": "https://www.amazon.co.uk/Boot-Buddy-fastest-simplest-footwear/dp/B014UPAHO4?pd_rd_wg=lVVK6&pd_rd_r=bf1ba871-fb59-4c66-a146-e94dde7c8e6d&pd_rd_w=gWC2F&ref_=pd_gw_ri&pf_rd_r=W68MX1TXFDDJ8Q8Z08CP&pf_rd_p=cecd4520-32f6-5499-ae19-cd4e83816acd",
            "name": "Boot buddy",
            "date": "2019-04-14 21:50:31.362",
            "price": "£14.99"
        },
        {
            "id": "1",
            "groupno": "1",
            "urlsource": "https://www.amazon.co.uk/dp/B07CH6JKW3/ref=gw_uk_desk_h1_aucc_cp_mp?pf_rd_p=e4e5a2e6-ddbd-473a-a5fb-e8cc09a11f88&pf_rd_r=1MN25BRXY8YDQ4TBK4X6",
            "name": "Amazon echo",
            "date": "2019-04-14 21:50:31.362",
            "price": "£19.99"
        },
        {
            "id": "2",
            "groupno": "1",
            "urlsource": "https://www.amazon.co.uk/Boot-Buddy-fastest-simplest-footwear/dp/B014UPAHO4?pd_rd_wg=lVVK6&pd_rd_r=bf1ba871-fb59-4c66-a146-e94dde7c8e6d&pd_rd_w=gWC2F&ref_=pd_gw_ri&pf_rd_r=W68MX1TXFDDJ8Q8Z08CP&pf_rd_p=cecd4520-32f6-5499-ae19-cd4e83816acd",
            "name": "Boot buddy",
            "date": "2019-04-14 21:54:11.184",
            "price": "£12.99"
        },
        {
            "id": "1",
            "groupno": "1",
            "urlsource": "https://www.amazon.co.uk/dp/B07CH6JKW3/ref=gw_uk_desk_h1_aucc_cp_mp?pf_rd_p=e4e5a2e6-ddbd-473a-a5fb-e8cc09a11f88&pf_rd_r=1MN25BRXY8YDQ4TBK4X6",
            "name": "Amazon echo",
            "date": "2019-04-14 21:54:11.184",
            "price": "£17.99"
        }
    ]
}
```

This the structure I want to achieve for the line graph...

```
[
    ['Date time',                   'Boot buddy price',     'Amazon echo price'],
    ['2019-04-14 16:00:29.595',     £14.99,                 £19.99],
    ['2019-04-14 21:50:31.362',     £14.99,                 £19.99],
    ['2019-04-14 21:54:11.184',     £12.99,                 £17.99],
]
```

I literally don't know where to start. Other questions/solutions I've found don't have the same original data format. Any help appreciated!

Comment: Could you please explain your desire output? Is it string or data? In the example you have 6 element but output 5?

Comment: if you can get the existing data into google's data table, then you could use google's data view and group method to get the desired result. see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53439490/5090771) for a _similar_ example...

Comment: @dWinder sorry I wasn't clear, I've updated the example to clearly show the desired output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can loop twice on your json - first get the data you want on array and format them.

First, loop on the json as:

```
$arr = jsone_decode($jsonStr, true);
foreach($arr as $e) {
    $data[$e["date"]][$e["name"]] = $e["price"];
}
```

Now, loop again on `$data` to format you output:

```
$res[] = ['Date time', 'Boot buddy price', 'Amazon echo price']; // set the header
foreach($data as $k => $e) {
    $res[] = [$k, $e["Boot buddy"], $e["Amazon echo"]];
}
```

And `$res` will contain your desire format